# Incorporating after receiving kickstarter funds

Tags: canada, business, ontario

I am currently in the process of launching my first Kickstarter croudfunding campaign as an individual. I don't have a lot of money left, and I don't want spend it incorporating, especially because my kickstarter campaign might not even reach its goal.

Is it possible to incorporate after receiving the funds on Kickstarter and then transfer them to that business bank account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

However, if you don't open a corporation or LLC and run the business yourself, even if you later transfer the funds to the company, you'll be personally on the hook for any lawsuits, because there won't be a limited liability. Please read up on the concept of [commingling funds.](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Commingling) and [piercing the corporate veil.](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/personal-liability-piercing-corporate-veil-33006.html)